# Limiting WebRTC bitrate: issues with Firefox

Tags: firefox, webrtc

I am trying to limit the bitrate of a WebRTC video stream sent from the browser.  With Chromium-based browsers, I simply set the `maxBitrate` field of the `sendEncodings` field at `addTransceiver` time.  Since Firefox doesn't support `sendEncodings`, I need to call `getParameters` on the sender, tweak its `encodings` field, then call `setParameters`.

This works quite well in the simulcast case; however, in the non-simulcast case (`encodings` is an array containing a single entry), Firefox appears to ignore the `maxBitrate` field, and always sends at its maximum bitrate (2.5kbit/s).

Is `encodings[0].maxBitrate` supposed to work in Firefox in the non-simulcast case?

Comment: have you compared to https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/bandwidth/ ? This still seems to work

Comment: It works, but it uses SDP munging, which is not something I feel comfortable with.

Comment: it does not use that codepath (unless your Firefox is really old)

Comment: Oh, you're right.  Let me check.

Comment: It turns out that Firefox doesn't like us setting the RID when we're not simulcasting.  This fixed it: https://github.com/jech/galene/commit/a698011aef9292638452cd658488988214ab651a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some investigation, it turns out that Firefox doesn't obey the bandwidth limitation in the non-simulcast case if the `rid` field is set.  So this works in both Chromium and Firefox:

```
let p = sender.getParameters();
p.encodings = [{maxBitrate: 700000}];
await sender.setParameters(p);
```

while this only works in Chromium:

```
let p = sender.getParameters();
p.encodings = [{rid: 'h', maxBitrate: 700000}];
await sender.setParameters(p);
```